# javascript/jquery using a changed element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

I was trying to automatize loading process of articles at my website but the line
    `$(tytul).html(data);`
is not working properly. I wonder is there any way to make this working?

```
    var numboart = 3;

$(document).ready(function(){

    for(i=0;i<numboart;i++)
    {
    var tytul = new String("\"#artykl"+i+"\"");
    $.ajax({
           url : "../articles/art"+i+".txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                $(tytul).html(data);
            }
        });
        }

});
```

I'm trying to put the txt files content into `'<div>'` elements which have ids #artykl1, #artykl2, #artykl3,... and so on.

```
            <div id="artykl1" class="post">




            </div>

            <div id="artykl2" class="post">




            </div>

            <div id="artykl3" class="post">




            </div>
```

Comment: please add too the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$.ajax()` is asynchronous, therefore there are no guarantees that on every loop you are injecting content inside `.post`. There are some solutions like use of `async: false`, use a `closure` or call a function (see the code):

```
var numboart = 3;

$(document).ready(function(){

    for(i=0;i<numboart;i++){
        loadContent(i);
    }

    loadContent = function(i){
        var tytul = "#artykl" + i;
        $.ajax({
            url : "../articles/art"+i+".txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                $(tytul).html(data);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

With this you ensure that `i` is correct on every `$.ajax()` call

**UPDATE**
If this not works, try to put the `loadContent` function outside `$(document).ready()`

Comment: This didn't help anyway :/

Comment: I had to put the 'loadContent = function(i){ } outside' of the '$(document).redy(function(){ } and it's working great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic id creation is not proper, it should be just

```
var tytul = "#artykl"+i;
```

You are constructing an selector like `"#artykl1"`, instead of `#artykl1` which is an invalid selector(you should have an error like `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#artykl1"` in your console)

Also you have a problem with [wrong use of a closure variable in a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

```
var numboart = 3;

$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < numboart; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            var tytul = new String("#artykl" + i);
            $.ajax({
                url: "../articles/art" + i + ".txt",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {
                    $(tytul).html(data);
                }
            });
        })(i);
    }
});
```

---

Also I think the code can be simplified as

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.post').each(function (i, el) {
        $(this).load("../articles/art" + i + ".txt")
    })
});
```

Comment: @TomaszMałachowski can you check whether the ajax requests are completed successfully

Comment: Thanks for your help, the simplification is working but not exactly the way i need it to. Unfortunately, Your correction for my code isn't working :(